# Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell. How can I resolve this issue in selenium webdriver using POI?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, excel

I am trying to read data from an excel sheet and write on my application.But shows an error while trying to pass a numeric value using string. Please suggest me how can I resolve the issue. Please see my code and error screenshot below:

```
package ReadExcelData;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File src=new File("E:\\QA_Automation\\TestData_Excel\\TestInputData.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println("Total Row" + rowcount);

    for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++) {
        String data0= sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Test Data From Excel"+data0);
    }

    wb.close();


}

}
```

**Please check below image for the exception :**

[image]

Comment: Please check given code in My answer. If you found any errors let me know

Comment: In Excel sheet before entering a numeric value inside a cell ,enter ~ symbol(tild) and enter the value.
For Example: ~123.
This might help you.

Comment: You can use a POI DataFormatter to automatically convert any Cell type to String. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful to you..

Open the Excel sheet and select all (Ctrl+a) then right click and click Format cells then in number tab change the category to Text and click Ok...

[image]

Comment: you are welcome @ShirinAkter

Answer (score 3):

> **This exception is occurred when code try to read Numeric value as string. `Apache POI` will not convert from Numeric to String.**

---

### There are two solution :

**1. First convert cell type to string and Read it. Please check below code :**

```java
    import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.util.Locale;
        
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
        
        public class ReadExcel {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File src=new File("C:\\Users\\Sagar\\Desktop\\TestInputData.xlsx");
        
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
        
            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        
            XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("Total Row" + rowcount);
        
            for(int i=0;i<rowcount+1;i++) {
        
                System.out.println(i);
                //GET CELL
                Cell cell1 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0);   
                //SET AS STRING TYPE
                cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                String data0= cell1.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Test Data From Excel : "+data0);
            }
        
            wb.close();
          }
        }
```

**2. Get type first and print by its option. Please see the code:**

```java
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.util.Locale;
        
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
        
        public class ReadExcel {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File src=new File("C:\\Users\\Sagar\\Desktop\\TestInputData.xlsx");
        
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
        
            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        
            XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("Total Row " + rowcount);
        
            for(int i=0;i<rowcount+1;i++) {
        
                
                Cell cell1 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0);   
                
                switch (cell1.getCellType()) {
                
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                    break;
                    
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell1)) {
                        System.out.println(cell1.getDateCellValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                    
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    System.out.println();
            }
                
                //String data0= cell1.getStringCellValue();
                //System.out.println("Test Data From Excel : "+data0);
            }
        
            wb.close();
        
        
        }
        
        }
```

---

> Note : Please check loop condition.It is also wrong. My code will not skip last row.

Comment: Above both code will print any type data which cover by apache poi formats.

Comment: You can use a POI DataFormatter to automatically convert any Cell type to String.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Check if cell is numeric or String through this code

```
     if(MytempCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
       your code ...
     else if(MytempCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
      your code ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is the column holding only numeric cells you can approach with this:

```
for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++) {
    String data0 = String.valueOf(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
    System.out.println("Test Data From Excel" + data0);
}
```

The approach above is a pure java way to display data of double type. However if you need the formatting like you would have in Excel you should check this doc: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
*CELLNAME*.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
```

This works wonderfully and converts the data in the cell as numeric.

For operating on that value use:

```
*CELLNAME*.getNumericCellValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what datatype the cell is, you can use [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-). This returns the default string format for each cell type, and it won't execute Excel formulas (it returns the formula text).

[See `\\ modified` below]

```
package ReadExcelData;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File src=new File("E:\\QA_Automation\\TestData_Excel\\TestInputData.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println("Total Row" + rowcount);

    for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++) {
        String data0= new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0)); \\ modified
        System.out.println("Test Data From Excel"+data0);
    }

    wb.close();


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is adding the apostrophe before number in Excel cell --> Excel will treat it as text.

'123456

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.id("field on screen")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));

Comment: Hi, love seeing new answers to old questions, but I'm curious how this is different from the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the error:: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
--> Go to excel --> Put an apostrophe at start of numeric data cell.
When the code will run, it will consider the cell value as String and will not throw any such error.