# How to properly import a number from Excel?

Tags: automated-testing, test-data

Doing data-driven testing, I need to import numbers from an Excel sheet, but 23.50 was imported as 23.5 even after I re-formatted it.

I am planning to to add a zero to the end of this imported number, but it is not the best solution, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: hear you can fine solution https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/30257/24460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I do not think you are importing numbers from an Excel sheet, what you are importing is perhaps a string.

Can you please try this:

- Highlight your data cells from the Excel sheet,
- Format cells,
- Number -> Category -> Text,

This way, your numbers will be exported as they are typed instead of having all zeros trimmed away.